# CSS is not loaded in IE for the first time after the form submit

Tags: jquery

I have a form like `<form action="/search.php" method="GET" id="myForm">` and a submit button. When I click on the
submit button it performs two ajax calls.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    updateFirst();
    updateSecond();
});

function updateFirst() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/a.php",
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: "true",
        data: { mydata: $("#abc").val() },
        success: function(jsonData, textStatus, jqXHR) { }
    });
}

function updateSecond() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/b.php",
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: "true",
        data: { mydata: $("#xyz").val() },
        success: function(jsonData, textStatus, jqXHR) { }
    });
}
```

I have also written some logic on the form submit. I know this is weird but this how it is:

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(){
    this.submit = true;
    // Written some logic here

    return true;
});
```

So when I hit on Enter after filling the form fields it goes to the 'search.php' page but the CSS does not load for the first time in IE. When I'm seeing the console
there are no references to the CSS files in the head tag but when I reload the page everything works fine.

When I click on the 'Submit' button this issue does not seem to occur everytime but it does not work one out of ten times.

I know this is a very weired issue but I'll appreciate if anyone could suggest on this !!

Comment: Could this be browser caching old html without css?

Comment: Nope this is n't a browser cache issue. I have cleared the browser's cache and the temporary files. Still it does not work.